# Is it possible to create a shortcut of a file in windows and make it work as if it was the real file (image)

Tags: windows, directory, shortcut

I've got an application that shows images stored in a `/media` folder. So it is mandatory that the images reside inside the `/media` folder.

The problem is that my images are stored in local network units and mantained (replaced, etc) by other users.

Is it possible to create a shorcut to an image, store it in /media so that the application would work as if the image was in `/media`?

The normal windows shortcut is not working as it is a .lnk and the app is looking for example to image.jpg...

Comment: You can try symbolic links (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link).

Comment: @MarkShevchenko thanks for your comment. Symbolic links are not working, hard links on the other hand they are working...Although I need the functionality of symbolic links...